# Unable to upload images with React dropzone

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, react-dropzone

I am using react-dropzone to get files on my react application and i am trying to upload these multiple images using axios. Backend is in mongo+express. But, for some reasons, image is not being received at the backend.
MY react code is:

```
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("title", entry.title);
entry.images.forEach((image, index) => {
console.log(image) 
/*This prints out
File
​​
lastModified: 1599303132607
​​
name: "name.jpg"
​​
path: "name.jpg"
​​
size: 41142
​​
type: "image/jpeg"
​​
webkitRelativePath: ""
*/
    data.append("images", {
      name: "image" + index,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      uri: image,
    });
  });
return http.post(
    "/" + dataEndPoint,
    data,
  );
```

The dragdrop element is below:

```
  const handleDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    setFileNames(acceptedFiles.map((file) => file.name));
    files(acceptedFiles);
  };
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        textAlign: "center",
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 0.2,
        borderStyle: "dashed",
        backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
        color: "#bdbdbd",
        marginBottom: 10,
      }}
    >
      <Dropzone
        onDrop={handleDrop}
        accept="image/*"

        // minSize={1024}
        // maxSize={3072000}
      >
        {({
          getRootProps,
          getInputProps,
          isDragActive,
          isDragAccept,
          isDragReject,
        }) => {
          // additional CSS depends on dragging status
          const additionalClass = isDragAccept
            ? "accept"
            : isDragReject
            ? "reject"
            : "";

          return (
            <div
              {...getRootProps({
                className: `dropzone ${additionalClass}`,
              })}
            >
              <input {...getInputProps()} />
              <span>{isDragActive ? "" : ""}</span>
              <p>Drag'n'drop images, or click to select files</p>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Dropzone>
      {fileNames.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <strong>Images:</strong>
          <ul>
            {fileNames.map((fileName) => (
              <li key={fileName}>{fileName}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

On the backend, when I log req.body.images, it says *[ '[object Object]', '[object Object]' ]*.
So, when I try to log this array, it literally logs out out every single character:

```
1 o
2 b
3 j
4 e
5 c
6 t
7  
8 O
9 b
10 j
11 e
12 c
13 t
14 ]
```

Does anyone know what I could be possibly doing wrong?
P.S. I have tried with different headers on the client side. Nothing works

Answer (score 0):

with FormData, you should add each file using a sequential name. like so:

```js
const fd = new FormData();

files.forEach((file, index) => {
   fd.set(`file[${index}]`, file, file.name);
});
```

your server should be able to interpret this as an array of files from the client.

Comment: Instead of handling this and other edge-cases, I would recommend using a library that does this for you in a much more convenient way. For example: react-uploady

Comment: It didn't work either. I feel like, I am unable to get the complete file to upload. I am just getting its properties in a object format which gets converted to string.

Comment: if you can set up a running example on something like codesandbox I will be happy to have a look and figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Comment: Ok, Can you check: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-cherry-sex7g?file=/src/App.js Will that be enough? I haven't coded the server side.

Comment: youre wrapping the file object with another object of your own (lines 37-41) this will not work. You need to set the value of the FormData field to the Blob/File as I've shown in the answer above. The other params you should pass as other fields in FD, not inside your custom object.

Comment: Please share the code youve tried. Id also recommend again, using a 3rd party. unless you really want to do it on your own

Comment: Check the link again. The whole issue is that the server is not receiving the file. It is receiving string.

Comment: with the new code it works as expected. I tried it with my local mock server and the actual file **is being sent**.  [network tab](https://res.cloudinary.com/yoav-cloud/image/upload/v1599473093/stackoverflow/Screen_Shot_2020-09-07_at_13.02.30.png) [server log](https://res.cloudinary.com/yoav-cloud/image/upload/v1599473093/stackoverflow/Screen_Shot_2020-09-07_at_13.02.37.png)